# R: Saved workspace have no variable in it

Tags: r, workspace

Workspace can be saved successfully, but once I open it , there is nothing in it as I run ls() in that workspace and found that:

ls()
character(0)

and that saved workspace all have 1KB size.

but after I loaded it using 
load("xxx.Rdata") 
It works and all variables is actually there.

Is there anything possibly wrong with my computer or could you tell me the way to fix that?
I used the same code to run and save workspace before I installed R 3.2.4 and it works just fine.

Please ^^

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what the problem is here. How do you open the workspace? Why is it surprising that the variables show up after loading the data with `load`?

Comment: I opened the  workspace by 1) double click on the saved workspace  2) open R and load that workspace with load("xxx.Rdata") the first way(double-click) didn't work as there's no variable in it .but the second works,all saved variable listed,when I call variable using ls().I used the same code before and I could opened (double click) the saved workspace and listed the variable w/o loading it.Also all saved workspace has its size varied,now It's all 1KB in size,So I wonder if there's anything wrong with my computer. Anyway,thank for stoping by.^^

Answer (score 0):

In R console, there are two options for Workspace. 
Saving Workspace as `xxx.RData`. 
Close R.

Double click on `xxx.RData` where you saved and it will open in R. type `ls()`

OR

Open R

Go to File --> Load Workspace --> Select `xxx.RData`, type `ls()`

or

```
>load("xxx.RData")
>ls()
```

Comment: Yes,I've tried both ways but double click on the workspace doesn't work,I can opened it but when ls() it return character(0). but when I loaded it use >load("xxx.RData")  it work just fine.Do you have any idea why this happened? Thank you very much ^^